# QUERY IMPORTRANGE Limitations

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language, importrange

I have a back end data sheet that needs to be queried from another sheet to populate dropdowns on the main sheet. The datasheet has less than 2000 rows and the `query(importrange` is skipping pulling in some rows from the datasheet. If I remove all other extraneous data and limit to the dataset I need it will import correctly. I am just wondering if there is garbage in the other rows causing it to not function correctly.

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("sheetID","Wage Codes!A1:C2000"),"select Col3, Col1 WHERE Col2 contains "&'Job Number'!A1&"ORDER BY Col2 ASC",1)
```

Comment: I figured it out. One of the columns in the data source sheet was set to Text format instead of automagic.

Answer (score 0):

the formula is correct.

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("sheetID", "Wage Codes!A1:C2000"),
 "select Col3,Col1 
  where Col2 contains "&'Job Number'!A1&"
  order by Col2", 1)
```

make sure that A1 and Col2 have set same formatting (Number)